# Problem while uploading chrome extension .pem file

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just made my first chrome extension but while uploading usually we have to leave the private key file optin blank first time but when i am doing so then its saying value name missing or invalid.

Comment: Where are you uploading it to? Official webstore expects a zip archive with sources.

Comment: Actually I am just want to test my extension first and hence I am trying to add it to my chrome only. But it is asking for the key which I don't have.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://extensions/`, click "Developer mode", then "Load unpacked extension" button, and select a folder with your extension.

Comment: yup the same thing I am doing there only as when we upload using packed option then we just have to select the folder and leave the  key option blank but in my case its saying value name missing or invalid and not allowing me to add the folder..